# Js цикл While (баг в коде)

Tags: javascript, while

Есть input i-81 и i-82 куда пользователь может ввести числа больше нуля.Если пользователь ввел 4 и 8 и нажал кнопку, мы получим: 4 5 6 7 8

код работает через раз
в чем проблема?

```
let button = document.querySelector('.b-8').onclick = function f8() {
let input1 = document.querySelector('.i-81').value;
let input2 = document.querySelector('.i-82').value;
let out = document.querySelector('.out-8');
while (input1 <= input2) {
    out.innerHTML += (input1 + " ");
    input1++;
}
```

}

Comment: как это "через раз"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что первоначально `input1` и `input2` - строки.

```
let input1 = +document.querySelector('.i-81').value;
let input2 = +document.querySelector('.i-82').value;
```

Comment: Конкретно код  с 4 и 8 будет отрабатывать и так, и проблем "через раз" не будет))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я думаю "код работает через раз" - "это неправильная печать" ("Осенний марафон").